# Is there an easy way for context specific navigation after a pop up window is opened

Tags: java, velocity

Please see my scenrario of returning back from previous page. Attached is the layout[image]

I have a HTML page say page1 and clicking on details button it would load 'details' page and on details page there is a back button which will navigate to previous page.Also there is another  page 'list page' which when clicked on details button navigates to details page and again back
should bring back to previous page. The problem here is the details page has lot of pop up windows (should say more than 25) as shown below.[image]

You can see on clicking of each magnifying glass there will be a pop up opened .
What i am trying to put is a value(1 for page1,2 for List page) at each of the pop up url and when refreshes it would send the same to parent page so that which back navigation will be decided. I am looking for alternate solution if there are any like even if pop up window is opened you can still retain the original value something like that..
Note that pop up was  opened through sending values to java.
This was developed using velocity template and java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening the popup, you have to store your context value (1 or 2) in [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) with `setAttribute` method.

When the back button is pressed, the servlet gets the page to refresh from that context attribute with `HttpSession.getAttribute("popupContext")` for instance.

I recommend you to remove this attribute from `HttpSession` (`removeAttribute`) when refreshing to avoid troubles later.

If each page is generated thanks to a specific path, you can get it from [HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) and use it as context. Then the back operation consists in a redirect to that previous location.

Comment: I mean I am ok with the suggestion and I had the same in my question as well.But its exhaustive because of handling too many URLs.

Comment: In that case, use the page request path as context from ServletRequest attributes.